# Need a Code Coverage tool for application in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, code-coverage

My Application runs on NodeJS and my Test Automation is in Java. I am looking for an appropriate code coverage tool.

Kindly excuse if inappropriate question. I am a beginner.

Comment: [http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/]Istanbul is a popular choice

Answer (score 0):

@AnshulG, I think you can not make a code-coverage report without tricks.

> Code Coverage is a measurement of how many lines/blocks/arcs of your
>   code are executed while the unit tests are running.

You don't have unit tests, because the application written in Node.js, tests are written in Java.